# How do I rollback to Firefox to 3.6 from a PPA version?

Tags: firefox, ppa

I foolishly upgraded my Firefox install on Ubuntu to the beta 4 release, I believe by adding the PPA repository -- is there an easy way to roll it back to the 3.6 version provided by Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you give some details about how you did the install?  Specifically, did you: a) install via a custom apt repository; b) install directly via a .deb package; c) install the binary directly?

Comment: He installed it through the PPA, as it says in the original post :)

Comment: Hi Thomas-- he had asked for info and I edited the original post ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, try these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa
```

Which will remove the PPA, `sudo apt-get remove firefox-4.0` to remove Firefox 4.0, and `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` to refresh the repository sources and upgrade (downgrade) "Namoroka" to plain old Firefox 3.6.

Comment: thanks thomas-- I get the following error: sudo: ppa-purge: command not found

Comment: @julio: sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

Comment: thanks alin! didn't realize it needed to be installed first.

Comment: ok, I did this and removed FF4-- however when I refresh and then upgrade, there's no changes made (no install of 3.6 )-- any ideas?

Comment: Wait, so Firefox 3.6 isn't even installed anymore?

Comment: @thomas-- I am not sure how to determine that. I had the daily PPAs in my sources list, until they were disabled on upgrade from 10.01 to 10.10. After that, naturally, I was stuck on FF 4.0 beta 8. I removed the PPAs and purged them, but no rollback happened.

Comment: Open up the terminal and type `firefox` and then click Help > About Firefox

Comment: it's Firefox 4.0b8

Comment: Hmm, this is really weird. And you did `sudo apt-get remove firefox-4.0` and then `sudo apt-get install firefox`? If these don't work then I honestly don't know. Sorry.

Comment: @Thomas Boxley-- thanks for all your help, this last comment actually solved it-- I simply did a `sudo apt-get remove firefox`, then `sudo apt-get install firefox` and it pulled in the proper FF 3.6

Answer (score 2):

If you want a GUI way then you can install [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) ([Download Link](http://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/0.5.x/0.5.10/+download/ubuntu-tweak_0.5.10-1_all.deb)) then run it from Applications -> System Tools.
Then navigate to "Package Cleaner" and click unlock and select Purge PPAs and select mozilla daily ppa

[image]

Then click cleanup and yes to the subsequent dialog

[image]

Now launch the software center and search for firefox-4.0 and remove it

[image]

Now search for firefox and install it.

[image]